# JQuery Mobile ajax load on external links

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm developing a JQuery Mobile application which loads from two different domains. (some pages are from example1.com, and other pages are from example2.com , but all of pages are designed by JQuery)

As far as I know, if I have a link from example1.com to example2.com, it will fully reload the page.

Isn't there any way to do dynamic ajax loading of that page, just like internal links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html) if the page is on another domain it will load the page with a full page refresh.

I haven't tested it myself but you should be able to first load the page using the [`$.mobile.loadPage`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) method and then link or change to that page which will now be part of the same DOM.

Answer (score 1):

See below:

> External page linking
>
> jQuery Mobile automates the process of building Ajax powered sites and
>   applications.
>
> By default, when you click on a link that points to an external page
>   (ex. products.html), the framework will parse the link's href to
>   formulate an Ajax request (Hijax) and displays the loading spinner.
>
> If the Ajax request is successful, the new page content is added to
>   the DOM, all mobile widgets are auto-initialized, then the new page is
>   animated into view with a page transition.
>
> If the Ajax request fails, the framework will display a small error
>   message overlay (styled in the "e" swatch) that disappears after a
>   brief time so this doesn't break the navigation flow. View an example
>   of the error message.
>
> Local, internal linked "pages"
>
> A single HTML document can contain multiple 'pages' that are loaded
>   together by stacking multiple divs with a data-role of "page". Each
>   'page' block needs a unique ID (id="foo") that will be used to link
>   internally between 'pages' (href="#foo"). When a link is clicked, the
>   framework will look for an internal 'page' with the ID and transition
>   it into view.
>
> It's important to note if you are linking from a mobile page that was
>   loaded via Ajax to a page that contains multiple internal pages, you
>   need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link. This
>   tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax
>   hash in the URL. This is critical because Ajax pages use the hash (#)
>   to track the Ajax history, while multiple internal pages use the hash
>   to indicate internal pages so there will be conflicts in the hash
>   between these two modes.
>
> For example, a link to a page containing multiple internal pages would
>   look like this:
>
> Multi-page link Here is an
>   example of a 2 "page" site built with two jQuery Mobile divs navigated
>   by linking to an ID placed on each page wrapper. Note that the IDs on
>   the page wrappers are only needed to support the internal page
>   linking, and are optional if each page is a separate HTML document.
>   Here is what two pages look inside the body element.